# How can I change this code to find the transform of objects with a specific tag instead of a specific object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code tries to find the player and have the zombies play an animation as they do it. My problem is that it isn't following the player however I know why. The reason this happens is because it isn't selecting the player, it selects the prefab of the player in the assets instead of the one in the hierarchy and it makes them buggy. This happens because I have a spawn manager that spawns in the player instead of just placing it in the scene because I want to make the player have a random spawn. I also want a random spawn for the zombies so I can't just add them in the unity editor. I think I can fix this problem if I can make the zombies track the players tag instead of the gameobject. Is there a way to change the code to make it track the players tag? Also if it is not possible please tell me because I don't want to waste time on finding a solution that is not possible. Thanks

Sorry if the code is bad I am a noob.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZK_Attacking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 3.5f;    
    public float AttackRange = 1.0f;
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(Player);

        float dstSqr = (Player.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;        
        bool inAttackRange = (dstSqr <= AttackRange * AttackRange);        
        anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", inAttackRange);
        transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Player.position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

Comment: `Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("YourPlayerTag")[0].transform;`

Comment: @TEEBQNE I tried it but I got the error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Comment: Sorry did not look close enough at your question and assumed `Player` was a `GameObject`. Updated the comment to properly grab the transform.